# How to create,delete and create a brand new git branch at cloud9 IDE?

Tags: github

I created a branch entitled 'contact',it didn't work as i expected so i deleted the branch and finally created it again.When i push it to git, i get an error.Exactly what git commands should i write at cloud9 so as to create the same branch successfully?Thanks.Here are the logs:

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Answer (score 0):

To create a branch,delete,then create the same branch,write:

```

```
git checkout -b name_of_branch

tip

git reset --hard
```

```
then,checkout the new branch to create